# "Augur" vs. "Oraclize" : What is the main difference?

Tags: oracles, decentralization, augur

Can we say that "`Augur`" is a decentralized Oracle against "`Oraclize`" as a centralized model?

I mean can we consider `Augur` as a decentralized Oracle and on the other hand, `Oraclize` as a centralized model? I say this based on **this article**: [LINK](https://medium.com/@DelphiSystems/the-oracle-problem-856ccbdbd14f). Since in `Augur` there is a **consensus** between a group of distributed data carriers. (I am not totally sure about that.)

Form `Augur` [white paper](https://www.augur.net/whitepaper.pdf):

> *Augur is a trustless, decentralized oracle and platform for prediction
>   markets. The outcomes of Augur’s prediction markets are chosen by
>   users that hold Augur’s native Reputation token, who stake their
>   tokens on the actual observed outcome and, in return, receive
>   settlement fees from the markets.*

And does it mean that `Augur` is used only for the *"market prediction"* ?

Comment: that's a nice way of putting it. the "potential" is certaily there, however, Augur is brand spanking new (just hit the Mainnet) and does not "yet" have the wide breadth of resources that Oraclize currently supports. so i'd say if you need a solution TODAY, stick with Oraclize